# How do I make CSS take into account a sidebar with absolute positioning

Tags: css

Im having a hard time whilst trying to learn CSS. I cant seem to figure out how to make the relative positioned div take into account the absolute positioned div's text.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<center>
<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I make it so that the lines expand till the end of the text in the sidebar?

Thanks

Comment: Long story short, you can't. div with `position: absolute` has no physical impact on it's parent width and height - hence it overflows. Possible solution would be to use `flexbox` or `float` instead.

Comment: You mean you want it to get the same height? That is not possible; absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal layout flow, so it can not influence the height of its parent any more. You rather failed to mention what you actually want to achieve here - but from what you have shown so far, it doesn't look like absolute positioning was necessary or even sensible here. You might get the desired result(?), if you float the inner div, instead of positioning it. (That by itself will not make the outer div encompass the inner - go research "containing floats" in that regard.)

Comment: Use `height` in terms of `px` unit for `relative` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the comments mention, it is indeed not possible for the parent element to adjust its height to contain the child, if the child is absolutely positioned.

If the relative and absolute positioning is not a must, then you can achieve this effect using float or flexbox.

**Using `float` property:**

```css
div.relative {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.absolute {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
    <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
  </div>
</center>
```

**Using `flex-box` property:**

```css
div.relative {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div.absolute {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
    <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
  </div>
</center>
```

If there needs to be other elements on the right side, you will need to wrap all of them inside another container.

Comment: I have no clue how to add you as best answer but this helped. Thanks alot!